# Getting Error in Event Viewer - 8311 - Topology on SharePoint App Server

Tags: error, certificate

Hi All off late we have been receiving below error in Event Viewer. Previously the the page was working. Now getting error message 'Error in Yahoo finance service has occured !'

> An operation failed because the following certificate has validation
>   errors:\n\nSubject Name: CN=*.yahoo.com, O=Yahoo! Inc., L=Sunnyvale,
>   S=CA, C=US\nIssuer Name: CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,
>   OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US\nThumbprint:
>   071211108F3C32CD7D3F9A5E94AC8C3EC3BF2FD7\n\nErrors:\n\n The root of
>   the certificate chain is not a trusted root authority..

I googled it but not getting clear and easy answer to the issue.
Kindly advice am not aware about Certificates and installations of them

**I am working on SharePoint App Server.**

Comment: Are you talking about SharePoint Server?

Comment: Yes Aakash it is happening on SharePoint App server

Comment: You should add the full certificate chain, not the last one. Here is the sample of script: 
$rootca = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.x509Certificates.x509Certificate2("[Your RootCA Certificate]") 
New-SPTrustedRootAuthority –Name "[Your Certificate Name]" –Certificate $rootca